# Master page not available as LayoutPage when creating view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, layout, master-pages

I've saved a `site.master` file to my `view\shared` folder.
When assigning a new view to the controller I check the *Use layout or master page* from the Add view dialog.

When browsing the view/shared folder only `.cshtml` files are available, not the `.master` file.

I am using the Razor View Engine.

Why am I not able to select the `site.master` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Razor view engine doesn't use a `.master` file. This is specific to the WebForms view engine. Razor uses a layout file corresponding to `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. So save your custom master as a `.cshtml` file in the `~/Views/Shared` folder and it will appear when adding a new view.